# Having issues with templates in derived classes

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have a set of classes that are used to prepare data for serialization. All of them are derived from the base class `cBase`, which doesn't hold anything related to the question.

Among the derived classes there are:

```
class cValue: public cBase
{
public:
    cValue(){}
    template< class T > void set( const T & value ){ data_ = value; }

protected:
    QVariant data_;
};
```

This is the class for holding simple values like a string or a number. And here is a class to represent an object (basically something that can hold "name-value" pairs:

```
class cObject: public cBase
{
public:
    cObject(){}

    void addAttribure( const QString & name, cBase * value )
    {
        if( attributes_.contains( name ) )
            delete attributes_[name];
        attributes_[name] = value;
    }

    template< class T > void addAttribure( const QString & name, const T & value )
    {
        cValue * tmp = new cValue();
        tmp->set( value );
        addAttribure( name, tmp );
    }
protected:
    QMap< QString, cBase * > attributes_;
};
```

The purpose of this is to be able to add attributes both with already-created objects: `addAttribute(someName, someObject);` and with raw values: `addAttribute("name", 42);`

Now, as it is, this code compiles. However, if I try to create an object like this:

```
cValue *tmp = new cValue();
tmp->set( 42 );
cObject obj;
obj.addAttribure("The Answer", tmp);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qvariant.h:429:12: error: 'QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private
../../source/private/../include/MyClasses.h:36:51: error: within this context
```

The error appears on the line where `cValue`'s `set()` function is declared. 
Now if I remove the templated version of `addAttribute()`, and place the exact same code from that function into my main:

```
cObject obj;
cValue * tmp = new cValue();
tmp->set( 42 );
obj.addAttribure( "The Answer", tmp );
```

it works fine. I figure it has something to do with the fact that both `addAttribute()` and `set()` functions are templated, but I fail to understand how to fix this issue, or at least how to make a workaround.

*Note*: if possible, I would like to *not* make the classes themselves templated, only the functions.

Comment: Could this be an ambiguity problem as `addAttribure(const QString& name, cBase* value)` is the same as `addAttribure(const QString& name, const T& value)` when `T == cBase*`.  What if you explicitly stated `tmp->set<int>(42)`?

Comment: @cmannett85, you were almost right, it's an ambiguity problem indeed, but the line I had to change was `addAttribure( name, tmp );` in the templated `addAttribute()` function, which I changed with a more explicit `addAttribure( name, static_cast<cBase *>(tmp) );`. It's working now. Post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting the compiler to call `addAttribure(const QString& name, cBase* value)` when using `cValue`, because `cValue` is derived from `cBase`.  But as they are not an exact match, the compiler calls `addAttribure<cValue*>(const QString& name, const cValue* value)` instead.

That's why (as noted in your comment) calling `addAttribure(name, static_cast<cBase*>(tmp))` worked.

Comment: Overloading a function is almost always better than specialising the template (there are lots of questions related to this here in SO). And no, there is no ambiguity when `T` = `cBase*`; in this case, the compiler selects the explicit function rather than a template.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, and the reason why your fix with a cast works, is that the compiler only selects the non-templated function when you call it with exactly the parameter types of its signature. In this case, you are not using a `cBase*`, but a `cObject*`. True, the later can be automatically converted to the former, but the compiler sees that it can instanciate the template to create a function that exactly matches the parameter, so it selects that.

You may go with your cast:

```
addAttribure( name, static_cast<cBase *>(tmp) );
```

or you may use a base class pointer directly to avoid the cast:

```
cBase* pBase = tmp;
addAttribure( name, pBase );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the identification of the type. I had a similar problem with QT, but some time ago. Maybe you should try

```
template< class T > void set( const T & value )
{   
  data_ = QVariant::fromValue( value ); 
  // or data_.setValue( value )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with this:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_template_qualifier.htm

I vaguely remember my own member template functions not compiling before I explicitly qualified them as such.